# can't call to int, even if I make it public

Tags: c#

So I have this login attempt loop named 'Inlogpoging'. After 3 times it needs to give you the message 'login limited'. But I get errors at the end at the script, what's wrong about it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int inlogpoging = 0; inlogpoging < 3; inlogpoging++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status.Onaangemeld);
        Console.Write("Gebruikersnaam:");
        string Naam = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Wachtwoord:");
        string Wachtwoord = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Naam == "administrator" && Wachtwoord == "SHARPSOUND")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status.Ingelogd);
            Console.WriteLine("Welkom bij SoundSharp {0}!", Naam);
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Helaas, gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord niet correct.");
    }

    if (int inlogpoging == 3); //Right here <--
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Login limited.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's syntax error `if(inlogpoging == 3)` is enough and don't put semicolon there

Comment: @un-lucky removing single blank lines does not help, it actively harms readability. It's not a good edit

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error near `if`; Declarations are not allowed inside the `if`, these are for evaluating conditions. and also there is no need to terminate them with a `;` the following code may help you:

```
int inlogpoging = 0;
for (; inlogpoging < 3; inlogpoging++)
    {
        // do the operations here
    }
// change the if as below
if (inlogpoging == 3) 
    {
       Console.Clear();
       Console.WriteLine("Login limited.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does not do what you want. 
Consider code below, check comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {

        int inlogpoging = 0;//initialize int counter
        while(inlogpoging<3)
        {
          if (inlogpoging == 3) //if equal to 3 then stop loguin process
          {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Login limited.");
          }
          else {//if not 3 then process loguin
            Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status.Onaangemeld);
            Console.Write("Gebruikersnaam:");
            string Naam = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Wachtwoord:");
            string Wachtwoord = Console.ReadLine();

           //at this point increment counter
            inlogpoging++;

            if (Naam == "administrator" && Wachtwoord == "SHARPSOUND")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status.Ingelogd);
                Console.WriteLine("Welkom bij SoundSharp {0}!", Naam);
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Helaas, gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord niet     correct.");


               //need a exit point
               return 0;
            }
        }
      }
    }
```